# Is the implementation of my add to cart / remove from cart secure?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am building an ecom website and in order to implement an add_to_cart function I've done the following.

Clicking the add to cart button calls the javascript `add_to_cart` function that I wrote:

```
<button type="button" onclick = "add_to_cart({{ product.pk }})">Add to Cart</button>
```

This is the function:

```
function add_to_cart(product_pk) {
    let url = '/add-to-cart/' + product_pk.toString()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    })
}
```

the urls for this look like this:

```
path('add-to-cart/<str:product_pk>', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart')
```

and finally my view looks like this:

```
def add_to_cart(request, product_pk):

    cart = request.session['cart']
    cart.append(product_pk)
    request.session['cart'] = cart

    context = {'length_of_cart': len(cart)}

    return HttpResponse(content = dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

tldr: Click button, button calls js, js makes get request to url, url triggers view, logic in view adds product to cart.

I feel like this is pretty "hacky". Are there any security issues involved with what I've done here?

Comment: Things that cause side-effects should be done through a POST request, and with the CSRF token.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, that is what I think too. What could go wrong doing it like this? It feels as though I am making a post request without making a post request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel like this is pretty "hacky". Are there any security issues involved with what I've done here?

A GET request is *not* supposed to have side-effects. Indeed, as the [HTTP specifications say [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that **the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT** have the significance of **taking an action** other than retrieval. These methods **ought to be considered “safe”**.

You should make use of POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE to make requests with side effects.

Django will automatically try to validate a CSRF token if you make a POST request. This to prevent a vulnerability that could result in a malicious JavaScript file that uses the credentials of the logged in user to make requests. Django (aims to) prevent this by using a CSRF token. You add such token to the POST request as is explained [in the *AJAX* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax):

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function add_to_cart(product_pk) {
    let url = '/add-to-cart/' + product_pk.toString()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
    })
}
```

finally we should product the view to only accept POST requests with the [**`@require_POST`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST):

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def add_to_cart(request, product_pk):
    # …
```